# How to add a signing key in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, signing

We have made a blackberry build.
Just want to know how to add a singing key for that build

Answer (score 1):

Get a key from https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/ and once your order is processed you will receive 3 keys that you install (there are instructions sent with the email). After that, you can right click on your project in the left pane in Eclipse, go to Blackberry -> Sign with Signature Tool